# /run/network/ifstate keeps getting reset on reboot

Tags: networking, network-manager

I find that my `/run/network/ifstate` file keeps getting overwritten on boot. On this session I'd edit it to

```
$ cat /run/network/ifstate
lo=lo
wlan0=wlan0
eth0=eth0
```

But on next session (after a shutdown) I'd find it only contains

```
$ cat /run/network/ifstate
lo=lo
```

I try to audit it (before reboot) via

```
$ auditctl -w /run/network/ifstate -p war -k ifstate-debug
```

But `ausearch -f /run/network/ifstate -i` (on reboot) says no matches. Indeed,

```
# cat /var/log/audit/audit.log 
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1426930357.497:4645): auditd start, ver=1.7.18 format=raw kernel=3.2.0-77-generic auid=4294967295 pid=1413 subj=unconfined  res=success
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1426930357.598:25): audit_backlog_limit=320 old=64 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1426930357.866:26): login pid=1566 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=104 old ses=4294967295 new ses=1
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1426930364.214:27): login pid=1888 uid=0 old auid=4294967295 new auid=1000 old ses=4294967295 new ses=2
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1426930459.042:28): login pid=2805 uid=1000 old auid=1000 new auid=0 old ses=2 new ses=3
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1426930459.258:29): login pid=2806 uid=0 old auid=0 new auid=0 old ses=3 new ses=4
#
```

And I'm not sure how to interpret this.

The reason why I want to keep `wlan0` and `eth0` on `/run/network/ifstate` is because just having `lo` in it prevents me from controlling `wlan0` and `eth0`. I use a wired connection but there is also an (unreliable) WiFi hotspot in my area. I used to connect to that hotspot so my box automatically connects to it. However, I don't want it to do that anymore since being connected to that hotspot and my wired connection at the same time leads to a very frustrating experience.

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the hotspot's connection definition via the network manager applet (Edit Connections --> Delete)?

Answer (score 3):

`/run/` is a `tmpfs` file system that only exists in RAM and is created anew on every system start. Any changes you make there are lost after shutdown.

To prevent Networkmanager to automatically connect to that hostspot edit the connection and switch off the "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" option.

Comment: Aw. That explains a lot. That is certainly an option but is there a way for me to configure what gets written into `ifstate` on boot? A month or so back I can disconnect from interfaces via network manager but not so now, presumably because of `ifstate`.

Comment: `ifstate` is managed by `ifup`/`ifdown`. If you add a connection with an `auto` stanza to `/etc/network/interfaces` that connection is brought up at boot time an a line for it is added to `/run/network/ifstate`. Most likely that's not the cause of your problem with MetworkManager.

Comment: Adding a connection with auto did not add an entry to `/run/network/ifstate` for me.  Raspbian Debian Stretch lite